# Oracle Weblogic server - get logs of requests served

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I am using Oracle weblogic server 11g. I came to know that logs are created at this location
"Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs"

I want to get following logs.

- All requests that were received by weblogic server.
- Count of requests that were served and requests that were not served.

I could not find these logs.

Comment: So... you want the access log? Do you have logging configured? I'm not sure what your question is. Do you only have an admin server, or also a managed server?

Comment: There is also a `AdminServer\logs\access.log` file that shows http requests and a security log, `DefaultAuditRecorder.log` that shows generic security info. You'll need to add more details on what you're looking for.

Comment: Alex, Please tell me how to configure logging for all requests made to srever. I am using admin server.

Comment: Is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/logging_services.htm#WLLOG116) what you are looking for ?

Comment: No Edi, 
This was my solution 
http://localhost:7001/consolehelp/console-help.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=page&helpId=logging.EnableAndConfigureHTTPLogs

Comment: Glad you solve it, if you can share with us the link from above, will be nice, so we can all see what is the fixture you were looking for - all the best !